# Hosting my ASP.NET MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What do I need to do to my Windows 2008 / IIS 7.5 server to allow me to host my new MVC3 applications. It already has .NET 4.0 Framework installed...

I dont want to use the /Bin deployment that I read of on the Internet.

Thanks Paul

Comment: Whats wrong with bin deployment?  Makes server maintenance easier.  Do you want to have to upgrade two machines whenever you install a new MS library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to run the MVC3 installer!

Answer (score 2):

All of the DLLs required by your app that are not part of the framework itself SHOULD be deployed into your applications ~/bin folder. Putting DLLs in the GAC is evil.

Benefits of ~/bin deployment:

1. Your application is guaranteed to have the *correct* (which is **not** always the same as *the latest*) version of each assembly that it requires
2. Redploying your application keeps those dependencies in sync with your app's requirements.
3. If you remove the app from the server, you don't leave shrapnel from the installation laying around that is no longer required.

~/bin installation is much, much cleaner than any alternative. I'd like to hear your reasons for avoiding it.

Requirements for MVC3:

1. [Download and install MVC3.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)
2. [Update your web application project to reference the MVC3 assemblies](http://mattsieker.com/index.php/2010/11/21/converting-asp-net-mvc2-project-to-mvc3/). (You might create a new, empty MVC3 app and compare the assembly references it includes)
3. Rebuild and run your unit tests. (You do have a test project, don't you?)
4. Have a serious look at Razor - it rocks.

Comment: The only downside to that is when dealing with current MVC3 RTM/Beta if you have any version installed in the GAC that will always be used over the version you have in the /bin because the version numbers weren't changed.

Comment: nice answer, but I have a beef with you on the unit tests comment. Not everyone uses them nor cares to use them, yet you make it sound like it's a life or death requirement... Otherwise, I agree with everything you said.

Comment: @Alex I think you're misreading my answer. I didn't threaten life, death or public humiliation upon those that aren't unit testing - just like to encourage it. For small-scale apps or single-dev teams, it's frequently overkill. I assume that's where the -1 vote came from?

Comment: and I think you disregarded the remainder of my comment where I agreed with you. And it was just that, a comment, and I actually voted you up, so your assumption is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It's refers to MVC2 but should work all the same
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/07/13/server-installation-options-for-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

If you have access to RDP into your server perhaps the Web Platform installer is the "easiest"

http://www.asp.net/downloads